# how to make a vector that classifies another vector

Tags: r

Suppose I have vector A of numeric integer data, and I want to get a new vector B of the same length, such that in the corresponding place, if the data in vector A is negative, it is "a" in vector B, if it is 0, then it is "b", and "c" for positive? 
eg:

```
v1<-c(1,-1,-2,0)
```

So I want to get a v2 like this

```
c("c","a","a","b")
```

Is there a slick way of doing it?

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: I considered using for loop, but I'm really new to R, so it seemed quite long and wasting....

Comment: Very raw: `letters[1:3][sign(v1) + 2]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very raw:

```
letters[sign(v1) + 2]
# [1] "c" "a" "a" "b"
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally, `ifelse` works for things like this:

```
ifelse(v1 < 0, 'a', ifelse(v1 == 0, 'b', 'c'))
```

You can also use `cut` for arbitrary interval-binning and labeling:

```
cut(v1, breaks = c(-Inf, -.5, .5, Inf), labels = c('a', 'b', 'c'))
```